# I always get the wrong data while importing from a website in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get full page balance sheet data from a Turkish stock website, however I always get the percentage data instead of the main data. Can someone help me to get the right one?

Thanks for your help.

For instance, the data I want is: "1.279.194", but I get "%-65".

Here are the codes I tried:

`=IMPORTHTML("https://fintables.com/sirketler/ASELS/finansal-tablolar/bilanco";"table";2)`

`=IMPORTXML("https://fintables.com/sirketler/ASELS/finansal-tablolar/bilanco"; //tr")`

[Website](https://fintables.com/sirketler/ASELS/finansal-tablolar/bilanco)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=importxml("https://fintables.com/sirketler/ASELS/finansal-tablolar/bilanco";"//tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[2]/div[1]/span[2]")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can I get the whole table with one formula, or should i try to get one at a time?

Comment: can try: `=importhtml("https://fintables.com/sirketler/ASELS/finansal-tablolar/bilanco","table",)` but looks like the value and percent scores are mixed up and all which you need to look into on how to fix it